# How to start a bash session from fish

Tags: bash, shell, fish

On Ubuntu, I have [fish](https://fishshell.com/) installed, and have it set as my default shell using `chsh -s /usr/bin/fish`.

I would like to open a bash shell. Entering `bash` creates a new fish session. How can I open bash without ending my login session?

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that `bash` starts a new `fish` session?

Comment: Erroneously. I assumed bash would set the `SHELL` env var. I was getting a bash shell (confirmed by testing `echo $(echo hey)`, which is bash-not-fish syntax), but `SHELL` was still set to `/usr/bin/fish`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're typing `bash` and ending up in a `fish` shell it almost certainly means you have put `exec fish` in your *~/.bashrc* script. Which is a commonly used technique to make fish your "default" shell without the risk that `chsh -s /usr/bin/fish` entails. Just remove that line from your .bashrc now that you no longer need it.